# Getting an invalid token on an interpolated string sent from python/jinga2 backend

Tags: vue.js, jinja2, interpolation

I'm sending a variable called apiID from a tornado/jinja2 python file to my vuejs template like this:

```
class SmartAPIUIHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self, yourApiID):
        doc_file = "smartapi-ui.html"
        dashboard_template = templateEnv.get_template(doc_file)
        dashboard_output = dashboard_template.render(apiID = yourApiID )
        self.write(dashboard_output)
```

then in vuejs I'm interpolating the variable with no problem except it gives me an error
[image]

it says: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

I checked on the python handler file and apipID is a string, so I don't see the problem.  I'm quite new to python so maybe the answer is more obvious to one of you.  I appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of `dashboard_output = dashboard_template.render(apiID = yourApiID )`, you must have, in your template, something around the code:

```
this.apiID = {{ apiID }};
```

Due to the value being not a number but a string, add the `'`s:

```
this.apiID = '{{ apiID }}';
```

Comment: omg thank you, I thought it would just become a string because it was a string. TY!!